# VPS with no X server - need a remote WWW GUI to manage FTP accounts remotely

Tags: nginx, ftp, graphical-user-interface

I have a Linux VPS server with no graphic interface, and I do not want one.

I need a way to manage the FTP accounts via graphical interface using the browser, remotely.

One solution can be to Install cPanel/DirectAdmin, etc, so I can login from wherever and add/remove/edit FTP accounts.

The problem with this kind of management panels is that I should re-configure the whole NGINX server and the whole server is managed by those Panels. So not only FTP, but everything else www related. I want to avoi it.

Changing this data very frequently, as I do via CLI is not convenient and I would prefer to edit everything via a browser.

I'd like to know if there is some kind of "Panel" just for FTP management or FTP and EMAIL accounts management.

Comment: Why don't you script the cli over something smarter that could add/remove bulks of users for instance from a file uploaded by FTP ?

Answer (score 1):

Something that may help is [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) - it's a web-based UI that runs on its own port, so it won't interfere with your current webserver, and it can handle as much or as little configuration as you like/want/need.

A security point though, you should treat Webmin (or any web-based management utility) as a critical attack vector. Make sure you have strong passwords, keep Webmin up to date to ensure security vulnerabilities are patched and lock the port via iptables to certain whitelisted IPs for management - ideally you should have Webmin listening to localhost (`127.0.0.1`) and use SSH port forwarding for remote management.

Comment: While I'm comfortable running Webmin on the open web (i.e. not behind an SSH tunnel), I do recommend enabling two-factor authentication, and making sure Webmin is included in your regular update schedule (Webmin's security record is pretty good, with the last RCE or data exposure bug being several years ago, but no software of this size or complexity is flawless and running as root on millions of machines it is a very high value target, on par with ssh or similar).